# Время с 1900 года

Tags: java, дата

Есть дата в секундах с 1 января 1900 года: -699848845. Как вычислить нормальную дату?

Comment: В году примерно 31536000 секунд. То есть мы имеем полных 22 года. То есть это 1922 год. Далее поступаете аналогичным способом для остальных временных промежутков

Comment: еще нужно учитывать високосный год.

Comment: @mamba0767, там же вроде отрицательное значение? то есть вычитать надо, а не прибавлять.

Comment: @Grundy можно и отрицать, суть не поменяется

Comment: в случае минуса, это `1877-10-27 21:32:35`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Старое API (до Java 8):

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) ); // не указано, в какой зоне 1 января 1900, будет в UTC
cal.clear();
cal.set( 1900, 0, 1 ); // январь - нулевой месяц

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzzz" );
format.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) );

System.out.println( format.format( cal.getTime() ) ); // 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 Coordinated Universal Time

cal.add( Calendar.SECOND, -699_848_845 );
System.out.println( format.format( cal.getTime() ) ); // 1877-10-27 21:32:35.000 Coordinated Universal Time
```

Новое API (Java 8 `java.time`):

```
LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.of( 1900, 1, 1, 0, 0 ) // январь - 1 месяц
    .plusSeconds( -699_848_845 );
System.out.println( result ); // 1877-10-27T21:32:35
```

Результат выводится в современном календаре (ISO-8601), без учета временной зоны. Для дремучего прошлого, возможно, придется подключать [ThreeTen-extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/), где есть реализация юлианского календаря, и разбираться в предмете подробнее.

Comment: Круто! Спасибо) В копилку сохраню.

Answer (score 2):

Добавляем в зависимости `joda-time` и получаем результат:

```
public class TestDate {
    public static final DateTimeFormatter FULL_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").withLocale(Locale.getDefault());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.parse("1900-01-01", FULL_FORMATTER);
        int seconds = 699848845;
        System.out.println(FULL_FORMATTER.print(dt.minusSeconds(seconds)));
    }
}
```